# rubyでスクレイピングをしたいが、mechanizeがrequireできない

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, mechanize

スクレイピングをしようとして実行すると以下のように表示されます。
調べてもわからず困っています。どなたか解決方法をお願いいたします。

```sh
$ ruby scraping_image.rb

/Users/〇〇〇/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- mechanize (LoadError)

from 
/Users/〇〇〇/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'

from 
scraping_image.rb:1:in `<main>`
```

Comment: mechanizeはインストールしてますか。それともインストールしたのにエラーが出る状態でしょうか。

Comment: mechanizeはインストールしています。

Comment: mechanizeの公式サンプルコードを動かしてみても同様のエラーが出ますか？ (Googleのコードは gbqf を tsf にしないと正常動作しないと思いますが、それより先に LoadError が出るかがポイントです。) http://docs.seattlerb.org/mechanize/EXAMPLES_rdoc.html

Comment: scraping_image.rbにrequire 'rubygems'を記述して無事にスクレイピングできました。ありがとうございます。しかしプログラミングを始めたばかりで、理解が追いついていない状態です。rubygemsとはどういったものですか？

Comment: Rubyやgemをどのようにインストールしたのか教えて頂けませんか？

Comment: rubyはrbenv rehashを、gemはgem install mechanizeを実行しました。

Comment: 追加情報はコメントではなく質問を編集して追記してください

Comment: @user25601 質問者さんがご使用のRubyの場合、私の認識では本来 `require 'rubygems'` は不要のはずなんですよね……。このため、質問者さんの環境を詳しく教えて頂きたいです。`rbenv version` を実行した結果と `gem environment` を実行した結果を、差し支えなければ本文に追記して頂けませんか？

Answer (score 1):

`gem list` コマンドでインストール済みの gem 一覧を得て、mechanize があるか確認してください。macOS / Unix / Linux 環境では `gem list | grep mechanize` で見やすい出力が得られます。rbenv を使っていらっしゃるようなので、念の為確認してみてください。

Comment: mechanize (2.7.5)と表示されました。